# Is it possible to have a fragment in a LinkedIn Share link?

Tags: angular, url, linkedin-api, share

I'm trying to create a share button on the product page of my website. I'm able to do so but LinkedIn keeps removing the hashtag (fragment) from the URL. I need the hashtag as it is an identifier. I tried using a URL shortener but it still doesn't work.

Is there any way to use a fragment in a URL when sharing on Linkedin?

https://terabulk.com/en/product/test-price-entry#62e2d55a9e05867d94041eba

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&title={{currentProduct.title}}&summary={{currentProduct.title}}&url={{urlCurrentPage}}" #li></a>
```

Here's a sample URL. I try using TinyURL Angular plugin but LinkedIn still removes the fragment (the bit after the hash). I also tried encoding with encodeURIComponent to no luck.

Comment: its better for us to understand what is the end goal, if linkedin removes the query params, then its better you go for a different approach!

Comment: I think i will make the fragment into a param